# MongoDB aggregate match by array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

is there some way to match by an array, using aggregation on mongodb?
I have the following structure:

**students**

```
{
  _id: 67264264726476,
  name: "Student 1",
  email: "student1@email.com"
}
```

**followups**

```
{
  _id: 65536854685,
  student: 67264264726476,
  message: "This is a student follow up"
}
```

I've made the following query:

```
const followups = await this.modelFollowup.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'students',
      localField: 'student',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'student',
    },
  },
  { $unwind: { path: '$student' } },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { 'student.name': { $regex: term, $options: 'i' } },
        { 'student.email': { $regex: term, $options: 'i' } },
      ],
    },
  },
]);
```

How can I make it possible to match using an array, instead of the **term** variable?

Comment: Why not add student name and email in followup. If student changes their details, you can update student and followup.

Comment: Adding students information in the follow up collection will not work, because it can grow to hundreds of students and dozens of follow ups to every student. Also, I still don't know how it would be possible to filter for more than one student at the same time.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_qhwIj7eJ0T) what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you share the sample output?

Comment: @ray that's almost what I was needing, but it would need to use regex to match parts of the name or email. But after talking to the PO here, I suggested using just the ids to match, since all the ids will be available directly in the followups collection.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match the complete list of student names and email you can check this query

**Query**

```
db.followups.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "students",
      localField: "student",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "student",
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$student"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "student.name": {
            "$in": [
              "abc",
              "def"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "student.email": {
            "$in": [
              "xyz@email.com"
            ]
          }
        },
      ],
    },
  },
])
```

Here is the link to the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7koY7jmAy-1) to check the query

Comment: Hi, as mentioned above, this is almost what I needed, I just would need to match using regex. But the query changed to use ids instead of strings.

Comment: @Marcelo this solution works. Just replace the array for `$in` list with regex, like replacing `"abc"` with `/abc/i`, `"def"` with `/def/i". Due to some limitations in Mongo playground so it cannot be demonstrated, but it works in my local environment.